# Generating random result from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am trying to generate a random result from array using JavaScript. My goal is, when the user clicks the button, I want to grab a random result from array named 'favorites'. It only works once the page is refreshed, but when you click it at the second time, it returns the same result.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        var favorites = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://msn.com", "http://apple.com"];
        var favorite = favorites[Math.floor(Math.random() * favorites.length)];
        var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is " + favorite;
        alert(postmessage);
    });
```

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sj74K/1/

Comment: I would move the array outside but it looks ok

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var favorites = ["http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://msn.com", "http://apple.com"];
    var favorite = $.rand(favorites);;
    var postmessage = "hi my favorite site is " + favorite;
    alert(postmessage);
});


(function($) {
    $.rand = function(arg) {
        if ($.isArray(arg)) {
            return arg[$.rand(arg.length)];
        } else if (typeof arg === "number") {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * arg);
        } else {
            return 4;  // chosen by fair dice roll
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sj74K/2/

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: why? we need to check the type by using "===" only. am i right ?